# COUNT With MIN and DISTINCT

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that returns the information from visits of user in a month, but just for those users who dont have visits before the month. This visits are related with a "location" as to where was this visit made.

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(visits.cust_id), locations.name as location FROM visits
LEFT JOIN customer ON visits.id = customer.id
LEFT JOIN locations ON customer.location_id = locations.id
WHERE date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) = date_trunc('month', visits.visit_date) AND (customer.referral = 'emp' OR customer.referral = 'oth')
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT FROM visits
  WHERE id = customer.id
  AND date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) > date_trunc('month', visits.visit_date)
  )
GROUP BY visits.visit_date, visits.cust_id, locations.name
HAVING count(visits.visit_date) = 1;
```

And the result is:

```
cust_id |     location
---------------------
    1   |      Loc 1
    2   |      Loc 1
    3   |      Loc 1
```

On my locations table there are 3, so what I would like is for the result to be just the count of ids and location names:

```
 cust_id  |   location
---------------------
  3       |    Loc 1
  0       |    Loc 2
  0       |    Loc 3
```

I know I can wrap my whole query into a count and it would count the results, but it only gives me a 3, which is correct but I still need to join the table with the locations where it indicates where this count is from and list the others missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH x AS (
    your_query_here
)
SELECT COUNT(x.cust_id), l.name
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN x ON x.location = l.name
GROUP BY l.name
```

Eventhough I woul recommend changing your query to return the `id` of the location for using this in the join-condition. But in general, this gives you your result.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This gave me the expected result! :)